# Contact Form 7 - multiple recepients

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7, contact

I am working with CF7 and for email to admin, I would like the same email to be send on custom address.

The flow would be like this:

- user fill name, email and note
- send the form
- on the backend via **hook/filters** I will add **CUSTOM EMAIL** to "To" field
- email goes to "admin" + "**CUSTOM EMAIL**"

So the problem is to add **CUSTOM EMAIL** (which is store in custom field of page where contact form 7 shortcode is located).

And the second problem is basically the same, but this the I need shortcode in the **BODY** and replace is by custom content, which is again located in custom field in page.

Both can be get by POST ID (for custom post type). But how?

Comment: read this : https://contactform7.com/adding-cc-bcc-and-other-mail-headers/

Comment: Which is not useful, because I need to set the email after form is submitted and I can't have the email in form, because it needs to be setup safely on backend.

Comment: from where come this e-mail ? a meta of the post ? edit your question to give more details.

Comment: Added more details, is this ok?

Comment: you can add e-mail address with the filter [`wpcf7_additional_mail`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/contact-form-7/tags/5.1.5/includes/submission.php#L377)

Comment: and to customise the body, look at the filter `wpcf7_mail_components`